# CSS transition delay in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, transition

The text colour should change at the same time as the rotation and the background color when you hover over a circle.

Firefox, IE, Edge all animate as expected but Chrome delays the transition of the text colour as if it is waiting for the spin to finish before animating and even leaving a gap in between the spin and the text colour change.

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/YNZawG

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #122d40;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #7fb400;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
a > span,
a span span {
  display: block;
  transition: inherit;
}
a span span:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 40%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
}
a span span:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #122d40;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
a:hover span span:first-child {
  opacity: 0;
}
a:hover span span:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 
<a href=""><span><span>Space</span><span><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ita nemo beato beatior. Si longus, levis; Utinam quidem dicerent alium alio beatiorem! Iam alium alio ruinas videres. Tamen a proposito, inquam, aberramus. </span> </span></a>
<a href=""><span><span>Speed</span><span><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ita nemo beato beatior. Si longus, levis; Utinam quidem dicerent alium alio beatiorem! Iam alium alio ruinas videres. Tamen a proposito, inquam, aberramus. </span></span></a>
<a href=""><span><span>Support</span><span><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ita nemo beato beatior. Si longus, levis; Utinam quidem dicerent alium alio beatiorem! Iam alium alio ruinas videres. Tamen a proposito, inquam, aberramus. </span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies here:

```
a > span,
a span span {
  transition: inherit;
}
```

Is this transition actully needed?
Try removing the property.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #122d40;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #7fb400;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
a > span,
a span span {
  display: block;
}
a span span:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 40%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 40px;
}
a span span:last-child {
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #122d40;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
a:hover span span:first-child {
  opacity: 0;
}
a:hover span span:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href=""><span><span>Space</span><span><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ita nemo beato beatior. Si longus, levis; Utinam quidem dicerent alium alio beatiorem! Iam alium alio ruinas videres. Tamen a proposito, inquam, aberramus. </span> </span></a>
<a href=""><span><span>Speed</span><span><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ita nemo beato beatior. Si longus, levis; Utinam quidem dicerent alium alio beatiorem! Iam alium alio ruinas videres. Tamen a proposito, inquam, aberramus. </span></span></a>
<a href=""><span><span>Support</span><span><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ita nemo beato beatior. Si longus, levis; Utinam quidem dicerent alium alio beatiorem! Iam alium alio ruinas videres. Tamen a proposito, inquam, aberramus. </span></span></a>
```